Collaborative Planning, Forecasting, and Replenishment (CPFR) model
I'm trying to understand better the CPFR model but I can't find anywhere a numerical example of this.
I'm looking for a numerical example with solution for Collaborative Planning, Forecasting, and Replenishment (CPFR) model. Can anyone assist me on it?
I know that CPFR operates in a series of steps that are commonly categorized into four main activities:
Strategy & Planning: Partners establish the collaboration arrangement, including the goals, the scope of collaboration, identification of participants, and the decision-making hierarchy.
Demand & Supply Management: Partners share forecasts and plans to detect and resolve discrepancies between the demand forecast and the supply capabilities.
Execution: Activities related to order generation and order fulfillment are executed in accordance with the agreed-upon plans and forecasts.
Analysis: Monitoring of execution activities for predefined exceptions, assessing performance against metrics, and sharing insights for continuous improvement.
